# mips gcc toolchain

Tags: gcc, mips, cross-compiling

I was trying to set up a toolchain for Mips on Ubuntu, as per the instructions [here](http://linuxencaja.net/wiki/Gccmips). However, when I do `make CFLAGS="-Os -w"`, I get an error as follows :-

```
...
...
fi
echo timestamp > stmp-fixproto
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/bin/mips-elf-as', needed by `stamp-as'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mainuser/mips/gcc-obj/gcc'
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mainuser/mips/gcc-obj'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How could I go about correcting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Which occurrence of `make CFLAGS="-Os -w"` is it failing on?  From the error message, it looks like `mips-elf-as` has not been successfully built by the first stage of the process.